# Looking for year and model of this Bianchi

Tags: shimano, identify-this-bike, vintage

Cleaning out a storage unit of my father in laws. Anyone know about this bike? Looks like it’s a late 80s model.

[image]

Comment: I don't know quite why, but it looks weirdly proportioned - might be the large+low saddle, or the thick pipe lagging on the bars, but it almost looks like a child's bike.

Comment: Also the front wheel is not installed in the dropouts, which makes it look really low in the front.

Comment: It's the wrong color for an 80's Bianchi.

Answer (score 4):

It looks a lot [like the 1987](https://velobase.com/CatalogScans/1987Bianchi.pdf) or [1988 Strada](https://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/1213930-1988-bianchi-catalog-spec-sheet.html). With Grab On foam grips and probably a 19 inch frame.

[image]
[image]
They did make it in red
[image]
Here's one found in the wild with a picture taken from the correct side of the bike.
[image]

I was able to find a 1987 and [a 1988 catalog](https://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/1213930-1988-bianchi-catalog-spec-sheet.html) with the Strada listed. Red was available in both years. I did find [a 1986 catalog](https://saarf.london/2014/03/01/bianchi-1986-vintage-roadbike-catalog/) and did not find the Strada listed.
I found [a 1989 catalog](https://www.gringineer.com/blogs/gringineer-cycles-bike-blog/1989-bianchi-catalog/) that listed only the Strada LX. It had down tube shifters and did not come in red.

Comment: Nice find!   Yeah those foam grips look strange to modern eyes.   It has a really short head tube compared to your examples, suggesting it's a tiny frame